# html page parsing error, head moved into body

Tags: html, parsing

I have this html file which is not getting parsed correctly by any browser - the head ends up in the body!

http://oiseanach.org/temp/Title.htm

Both the Google Chrome and Firebug inspectors show some < > converted to HTML entities... I am not sure why?

Validation has the same problem with parsing:  ends up in the body etc.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Foiseanach.org%2Ftemp%2FTitle.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

I thought it might be some stray non-printable characters, but I cannot find anything that would be tripping out the parser. The file encoding is UTF-8, specified as UTF-8 in the HTML. Not a JS issue as it is the same with scripts disabled.

Any ideas what could be causing it to come out mangled?

Comment: You're missing the <HEAD> tag.

Comment: @Diodeus: No, it's there, but it's very short.

Comment: I see now, but there are all kinds of things that should be wrapped in <head> but are part of <body>.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to be the problem. The html is actually a dump of the output of a couple of PHP files which have the encoding error - and the malformed markup got dumped as well. I have not moved the </head><body> above the first <header> tag, and something is still not coming out right - the <style> is inserted into the body.

Comment: sorry, *I HAVE moved the tags in the html file now*. In Firebug I can see this strange whitespace in double inverted commas before where it breaks (i.e. after parsing, the code in he file seems ok). Shall I post a screenshot?

Comment: I solved the problem. I was inserting a stylesheet from a database as "text/html", rather than "text/css" on an ExpressionEngine install, which was breaking the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You close your head on the second line, no wonder browsers try to guess what you actually ment.

Answer (score 0):

The `head` tag only contains a meta tag for the content type. You have put everything else in the body, it's not something that the browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is malformed.  Meta and title tags go in the head section, not the body.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Your title here</title>
    <meta name="name goes here" value="correct location of a meta tag (in the head)">
  </head>
  <body>
    <meta name="bad" value="wrong location of a meta tag (in the body)">
    <title>Wrong location of the title tag</title>
  </body>
  </html>
```